# Agregar dinamicamente paginas en jspdf

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf, angular-cli, html2canvas

alguno o tiene una funcion armada ya funcionando de como generar hojas y mostrar el html que yo quiero con la cantidad de hojas necesarias en **jspdf** *lo que me sucede es que, me agrega las hojas que necesito pero no me muestra el codigo,* no encuentro una funcion que me lo logre hacer, me busque todas las soluciones posibles en **stackoverflo**w y nadie pudo solucionarmelo todavia, me darian una mano gigante. gracias

***El parametro id_reporte es el id del div enetero -que es largo- y necesito descargarlo como pdf con sus cantidad de hojas necesarias para poder mostrarlo completo, es un informe***

Muchas gracias gente!

```
 async downloadPDF(id_reporte: any, npre:number) {
    const DATA =  document.getElementById(id_reporte);
    const options = {
      background: 'white',
      scale: 3

    };
    html2canvas(DATA, options).then((canvas) => {
        var imgWidth = 210;
        var pageHeight = 290;
        var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        var heightLeft = imgHeight;
  
  
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        var position = 0;
        var pageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
        var imgData = encodeURIComponent(pageData);
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        doc.setLineWidth(5);
        doc.setDrawColor(255, 255, 255);
        doc.rect(0, 0, 210, 295);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        
        if (heightLeft >= 0) {
          position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
          doc.addPage([imgWidth, imgHeight]);          
         doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
          doc.setLineWidth(5);
          doc.setDrawColor(255, 255, 255);
          doc.rect(0, 0, 210, 295);
          heightLeft -= pageHeight;
          
        }else{
         
        }
  
         doc.save(`Orden N ${npre}`) 
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que he hecho ha sido utilizar domimage

```
async createPdf() {
    await this.loaderService.showLoader()
    const pdfBlock = document.getElementById("print-wrapper")

    const imgWidth = 210
    const pageHeight = 297
    const imgHeight = pdfBlock.clientHeight * imgWidth / pdfBlock.clientWidth
    let heightLeft = imgHeight
    let position = 0

    const options = {
        background: "white",
        height: pdfBlock.clientHeight,
        width: pdfBlock.clientWidth
    }

    domtoimage.toPng(pdfBlock, options).then((fileUrl) => {
        let doc = new JSPDF("p","mm","a4")
        doc.addImage(fileUrl, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)

        heightLeft -= pageHeight

        for(let i = heightLeft; i >= 0; i -= pageHeight) {
            position = i - imgHeight
            doc.addPage("a4")
            doc.addImage(fileUrl, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
        }

        this.loaderService.hideLoader()

        doc.save('user.pdf')
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```